# After insert to Map cant execute map contents

Tags: java

I have inserted console input to map but why its not get printed as per code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class One {

public static void main(String[] args) {        

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    while(s.hasNextLine()){
        String[] split = s.next().toString().split("-");            
        map.put(Integer.parseInt(split[0]), Integer.parseInt(split[1]));                    
    }   

    for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> e:map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(e.getKey()+"-"+e.getValue());
    }       
}

}
```

please let me know whats the reason.

Comment: Replace the two lines inside` while` loop with `String[] split = s.next().toString().split("-");
            System.out.println(split[0]+"-"+split[1]);`

Comment: @Bunti: But its not printing last line of input

Comment: You mean even if you change the `while` loop statements to the statements I have given in previous comment?. If the last line is not printed it suggests that you don't have new line character at the end of last line of your input.

Comment: @Bunti: yes you are right. thanks

Comment: @Bunti: One more thing.. inside while loop i am doing this map.put(Integer.parseInt(split[0]), Integer.parseInt(split[1])); and outside while loop i am using                                   for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> e:map.entrySet()){
   System.out.println(e.getKey()+"-"+e.getValue());
}   but i am not able to print map data. My map decalration is as follows: Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

Comment: Please update the question with necessary parts. It's hard to read code in comments.

Comment: @Bunti: updated please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that now you've incorporated changes suggested in comments. Now the problem with your logic is that you keep accepting inputs from the user and add them to the `Hashmap`. There is no way of getting out of that loop. As you're stuck in the `while` loop you would never see the data stored in `Map`. Modify the code as shown below so that you get a chance to break out of the loop.

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    while(s.hasNextLine()){
        String input = s.next();
        if (!input.equals("quit")) {
            String[] split = input.toString().split("-");
            map.put(Integer.parseInt(split[0]), Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> e:map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(e.getKey()+"-"+e.getValue());
    }
```

You may also add better error handling whenever malformed input is received.